# How to annotate C# struct field to be marshalled as pointer or nested in PInvoke?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke

In C++ there are following structures

```cpp
extern "C" {
    struct A_C {
        UINT32 number;
    }

    struct B_C {
        A_C nested;
        A_C* pointer;
    }
}
```

What is the proper attribute annotation of following C# structures

```cs
struct ACs {
    UInt32 number;
}

struct BCs {
    ACs nested;
    ACs pointer;
}
```

so that `BCs.nested` will be mapped to `B_C.nested` and `BCs.pointer` will map to `B_C.pointer`?

It can be achieved by implementing `ICustomMarshaler` but is there a solution without additional procedural code?

Comment: Since everything is a primitive, can you get an `IntPtr` to the whole structure? I mean without attributes or anything extra...

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, `Bcs.pointer` can be of type `IntPtr`. But I want PInvoke framework to unwrap that pointer directly to `ACs` structure.

Comment: I was thinking something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496773/1048799 ...they are using `StructLayout`, but that makes sense.

Comment: There are only few attributes that one can set on structure fields. There's nothing that would suit this case, you must use an IntPtr.